# Book series about a junior officer in the Polish Air Force

Tags: story-identification, alternate-history

I'm looking for a series of novels set in Poland that depict an alternate past and future.

In the first book, a junior officer in the Polish Air Force (I think) is on a walking tour.  He bought some seeds for his mother, but with a miniature nuclear accident he gets transported in time to the past.

I cannot remember much else, except for a genetically engineered horse in one of the later books.

Comment: Does he perhaps, also find a sword that is unusual for the period (light blade and very resilient, bendable metal)? I seem to recall this book, but not the title.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104686/time-travel-story-about-a-man-from-the-future-who-becomes-a-knight-his-allies-s (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time travel story about a man from the future who becomes a knight. His allies send him a genetically engineered horse](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104686/time-travel-story-about-a-man-from-the-future-who-becomes-a-knight-his-allies-s)

Comment: @DaveInCaz The OP never accepted an answer here unless I am missing something and so this is not a dupe.

Answer (score 10):

Is it the Conrad Stargard novels by Leo Frankowski? : [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conrad_Stargard)
Conrad is an engineer but he was in the Polish AF too.
The first novel is the Cross Time Engineer

Comment: Great series of books!