# Time travel story about a man from the future who becomes a knight. His allies send him a genetically engineered horse

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I have no idea about the name.  It was about a man who went back in time to the middle ages from the future. He stuck there.  He became a knight because of his understanding of modern science. And he spent time trying to build modern conveniences. The other thing that I remember is that his descendents from the future were able to help him by sending back a genetically enhanced horse.

The other thing that my teenage brain remembers is that he had many sexual escapades with the local women, and if they got pregnant, they would get married off, but there was one woman who was special and he tried not to get her pregnant.

Comment: What years were you a teen?

Comment: Sounds strangely like the *Doctor Who* episode "The Girl from the Fireplace"!

Comment: @DaveInCaz We don't add the work tag to a story id question when solved, see [meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12285/58193) for more info on it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The book you are looking for is [Cross Time Engineer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345327624) by [Leo Frankowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leo_Frankowski).

> **The main character Conrad Stargard is a Polish engineer from the year 1986. After getting drunk and falling asleep in a time machine, he is transported back in time to the year 1231. Conrad, familiar with Poland's history, knows that in 10 years the Mongols will arrive and kill most of the population of Europe. After befriending a local monk, and a failed attempt at becoming a scribe, he takes a job as a bodyguard to a merchant. Due to his skill at arms and mercy in saving the infant of bandits he had slain, he impresses the local count, Count Lambert. It is discovered at this point that Conrad's "amazing warhorse" and "superb weapons" were all planted by his distant cousin who invented the time-machines and wished to help Conrad. However due to causality, Conrad cannot be simply removed from the past, but he can be "assisted". After improving Count Lambert's industrial base by building a cloth factory and multipurpose windmill, Conrad is eventually granted land on which he can build his industrial base to defend Poland**

[Conrad Stargard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conrad_Stargard)

Comment: someone from the future goes to middle ages, check. he uses science, check. he has a genetically enhanced horse sent by his cousin(from the present/future), check.

Comment: Fair warning, the first four books are good. The fifth one gets weird and relies on a huge *deux ex machina*. The sixth and on drop seriously in quality.

Comment: Wow that is it.  I can't believe you found it.  I have tried several times to google it but no luck.  Thanks a lot.  I only ever read the first one and was always curious about how it ended.

Comment: Oh, and it looks like Baen has the first book available at http://www.baen.com/chapters/W200412/0743488636.htm

Comment: @WallyKroeker see sean duggan comment a free online copy of the first story if you want a free re-read

Comment: Is it odd that I was able to identify this book just by seeing the question title in the HNQ?

Comment: I read the first one many years ago--found it in a very-well-stocked thrift store. It was kind of fun.

Comment: What is funny to me is that it pops up in my memory from time to time so it obviously had an impact. But I could not tell you where I got the book or even remember the exact age I was when I read it.  Must have just been a library find.